# Compare two data frames with huge data, using render_diff() function from daff package in R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, bigdata, difference

I have 2 following data frames a1 and a2

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5]) ,

a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])
```

In order to get the HTML output of difference of a1 and a2, I used following command:

```
render_diff(diff_data(a1,a2))
```

It gives good output with color codings. However, The html output doesnt work with huge data. Is there any way I can edit the pagelength output for render_diff. 
I want to use HTML output for its color coding properties, where it gets easier to see the differences. Any suggestions?

Comment: How huge is the data ? Number of rows? columns?

Comment: The data would be around 10,000 rows max and column size can vary between 5-15.